# Select múltiple en Semantic-ui que no funciona

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3, semantic-ui

Estoy con Semantic-ui y armando un select multiple. Para ello pongo en el head de la pagina lo siguiente, como indica la documentación:

```
<script>
    $('.ui.dropdown')
        .dropdown()
    ;

    $('#select')
      .dropdown()
    ;

    $('#multi-select')
      .dropdown()
    ;
</script>
```

Por otro lado en el body tengo un combo simple con estas opciones:

```
<div class="field">
            <label>Tipo de Perfil:</label>
            <select id="select" class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple name="claseUsuario[]>
                <option value="1">Tipo 1</option>
                <option value="2">Tipo 2</option>
                <option value="3">Tipo 3</option>
                <option value="4">Tipo 4</option>
            </select>
            <span class="ui help"><small>No seleccione nada si es un usuario común</small></span>
        </div>
```

Ahora bien, ejecutado el código me sale una lista y no un combo como quiero que salga... Alguna noción de por que me pasa esto ?

Arriba de todo en el head defino los vinculos a los archivos js y css claro:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/semantic.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/semantic.css" >
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿puedes agregar una imagen de lo que te muestra actualmente?

Comment: ahi agrego una imagen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer cerraste mal unas comillas y agrega el código JavaScript antes de `</body>`.

```js
    $('#select')
      .dropdown()
    ;
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.js"></script>
<div class="field">
            <label>Tipo de Perfil:</label>
            <select id="select" class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple name="claseUsuario[]">
                <option value="1">Tipo 1</option>
                <option value="2">Tipo 2</option>
                <option value="3">Tipo 3</option>
                <option value="4">Tipo 4</option>
            </select>
            <span class="ui help"><small>No seleccione nada si es un usuario común</small></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: sabes que coloque las comillas y sigue sin funcionar... también modifique el orden del css y los js y tampoco... sigue igual...

Comment: Mira el ejemplo del snippet, es tu mismo código, funciona sin problema.

Comment: si si lo estaba revisando !!! por que sera ?

Comment: Probaste poniendo el JavaScript al final del código, antes de `</body>`?

Comment: siiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii era eso !!! gracias Shaz !!!